# SwiftUI- Chip Selection not working at parent view level only child level

Tags: swiftui

I am at a loss here and you will have to bare with me here.

So I created a chip view that is selectable at the sub-child level and the child level.

At the parent level the selection ability disappears and works halfway.

I allow up to 5 selections to happen and then after that you have to unselect to reselect something different. This works great at the child level.

However at the parent level you can select 5 items. Also they do not show selected and you can't unselect to reselect something else. They are however populating the array that they are being saved to.

At the parent and child level. At the parent level items are not being removed when you are trying to unselect because the selection aspect stops working.

In the lower levels I use a variable called isSelected to track.

So the sub child and child are populated from a model. The model is as followed.

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct ChipModel: Identifiable {
    @State var isSelected: Bool
    let id = UUID()
    let systemImage: String
    let imageType: String
    let titleCategory: String
    let titleKey: LocalizedStringKey
}

struct ChipBaseCategories: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let category: String
}

class ChipsViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var chipArray: [ChipModel] = [
        ChipModel(isSelected: false, systemImage: "basil", imageType: "Custom", titleCategory: "Fresh Herbs", titleKey: "Basil"),
        ChipModel(isSelected: false, systemImage: "basil", imageType: "Custom", titleCategory: "Fresh Herbs", titleKey: "Rosemary"),
        ChipModel(isSelected: false, systemImage: "basil", imageType: "Custom", titleCategory: "Fresh Herbs", titleKey: "Tarragon"),
        ChipModel(isSelected: false, systemImage: "basil", imageType: "Custom", titleCategory: "Fresh Herbs", titleKey: "Sage"),
        ChipModel(isSelected: false, systemImage: "basil", imageType: "Custom", titleCategory: "Fresh Herbs", titleKey: "Thyme"),
        ChipModel(isSelected: false, systemImage: "basil", imageType: "Custom", titleCategory: "Fresh Herbs", titleKey: "Mint"),
        ChipModel(isSelected: false, systemImage: "basil", imageType: "Custom", titleCategory: "Fresh Herbs", titleKey: "Hibiscus"),
        ChipModel(isSelected: false, systemImage: "basil", imageType: "Custom", titleCategory: "Fresh Spices", titleKey: "Cinnamon Stick"),
        ChipModel(isSelected: false, systemImage: "basil", imageType: "Custom", titleCategory: "Fresh Spices", titleKey: "Star Anise"),
        ChipModel(isSelected: false, systemImage: "basil", imageType: "Custom", titleCategory: "Fresh Spices", titleKey: "Fresh Cloves"),
        ChipModel(isSelected: false, systemImage: "basil", imageType: "Custom", titleCategory: "Fresh Spices", titleKey: "Rainbow Peppercorns")
    ]
}
```

I also have a class that I am using to save selections in. The only on in this class is the myDrinkGarnishAr which is the Array that saves the chip selections. I also use this variable to trap the count so I know when to not allow a selection. customdrink.myDrinkGarnishCount

```
import Foundation


class customDrink: ObservableObject {
    @Published var myDrinkName: String = ""
    @Published var myDrinkType: String = ""
    @Published var myDrinkSize: String = ""
    @Published var myDrinkServingSize: String = ""
    @Published var myDrinkBase1: String = ""
    @Published var myDrinkBase2: String = ""
    @Published var myDrinkSweet: String = ""
    @Published var myDrinkSour: String = ""
    @Published var myDrinkGarnishAr: [String] = []
    @Published var myDrinkGarnish1: String = ""
    @Published var myDrinkGarnish2: String = ""
    @Published var myDrinkGarnish3: String = ""
    @Published var myDrinkGarnish4: String = ""
    @Published var myDrinkGarnish5: String = ""
    @Published var myDrinkGarnishCount: Int = 0
    @Published var myDrinkGarnishSelected: Bool = false
}
```

Here is the item Chip View itself.  This is the single chip item and would be what I call the sub-child view.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ChipItemView: View {
    
    //MARK: - PROPERTIES
       
       @EnvironmentObject var customdrink: customDrink
       @State private var showingAlert = false
       @State var isSelected: Bool
       let systemImage: String
       let imageType: String
       let titleKey: LocalizedStringKey
       
       
       
       //MARK: - BODY
       var body: some View {
           VStack {
               HStack(spacing: 4) {

                   Text(titleKey)
                       .foregroundColor(.red)
               } //:END OF HSTACK
               .padding(.vertical, 5)
               .padding(.horizontal, 5)
               .padding(.leading, 10)
               .padding(.trailing, 10)
               .background(isSelected ? Color(.blue) : Color(.white)
               ) //:END OF BACKGROUND
                               .cornerRadius(20)
                               .overlay(
                                   RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                                       .stroke(Color(.black), lineWidth: 1.5)
               ).onTapGesture {
                   if customdrink.myDrinkGarnishCount < 5 {
                       isSelected.toggle()
                       customdrink.myDrinkGarnishSelected.toggle()
                       if isSelected {
                           customdrink.myDrinkGarnishCount += 1
                           customdrink.myDrinkGarnishAr.append(titleKey.stringKey!)
                           print("Less than five Add: \(customdrink.myDrinkGarnishAr)")
                       } else {
                           customdrink.myDrinkGarnishCount -= 1
                           if let index = customdrink.myDrinkGarnishAr.firstIndex(of: titleKey.stringKey!) {
                               customdrink.myDrinkGarnishAr.remove(at: index)
                           } //:END OF
                           print("Less than five remove: \(customdrink.myDrinkGarnishAr)")
                       }
                   }else if customdrink.myDrinkGarnishCount == 5 && isSelected == true {
                       customdrink.myDrinkGarnishCount -= 1
                       if let index = customdrink.myDrinkGarnishAr.firstIndex(of: titleKey.stringKey!) {
                           customdrink.myDrinkGarnishAr.remove(at: index)
                       } //:END OF
                       print("Equal than five remove: \(customdrink.myDrinkGarnishAr)")
                       isSelected.toggle()
                       customdrink.myDrinkGarnishSelected.toggle()
                   }else if customdrink.myDrinkGarnishCount > 5 {
                       showingAlert.toggle()
                       print("Greater than five: \(customdrink.myDrinkGarnishAr)")
                   } //:END OF IF
           } //:END OF ON TAP
           } //:END OF VSTACK
           .alert("To many selections Reduce one", isPresented: $showingAlert) {
                       Button("OK", role: .cancel) { }
                   } //:END OF ALERT
       } //:END OF BODY VIEW
   } //:END OF STRUCT


   //MARK: - PREVIEW

   struct ChipItemView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
       static var previews: some View {
           ChipItemView(isSelected: false, systemImage: "basil", imageType: "Custom", titleKey: "Basil" )
               .environmentObject(customDrink())
               .previewLayout(.sizeThatFits)
               .padding()
       }
   }

   extension LocalizedStringKey {

       var stringKey: String? {
           Mirror(reflecting: self).children.first(where: { $0.label == "key" })?.value as? String
       } //:END OF VAR
   } //:END OF EXTENSION
```

Then I pull this item chip view and build a container/another view and populate this chip model data.

```
 import SwiftUI

struct ChipContainerView: View {
    
    //MARK: - PROPERTIES
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ChipsViewModel()
    @EnvironmentObject var customdrink: customDrink
    @State var scrollViewOffset: CGFloat = 0
    @State var startOffset: CGFloat = 0
    @State private var pulsateButton: Bool = false
    
    let chipbaseButtonCategories = [
        ChipBaseCategories(category: "Fresh Herbs"),
        ChipBaseCategories(category: "Fresh Spices")
    ]
    
    var columns: [GridItem] = [
         
        GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 130), spacing: 0)

        ]
    
    //MARK: - BODY
    
    var body: some View {
        var width = CGFloat.zero
        var height = CGFloat.zero
        
        VStack {
            return GeometryReader { geo in
                ZStack {
                    Color(.white)
                        .ignoresSafeArea()
                    ScrollViewReader { proxyReader in
                        ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                            Spacer()
                                .id("SCROLL_TO_TOP")
                            VStack {
                                Text("Choose Up to 5")
                                    .padding(.top, 25)
                                ZStack(alignment: .topLeading, content: {
                                    LazyVGrid(
                                        columns: columns,
                                        alignment: .leading,
                                        pinnedViews: [.sectionHeaders]
                                    ) {
                                        ForEach(chipbaseButtonCategories) { chipbaseCategory in
                                            Section(header: Text(chipbaseCategory.category).font(.system(size: 15,weight: .bold)).padding(10)) {
                                                
                                                let catFilter = viewModel.chipArray.filter { $0.titleCategory ==  chipbaseCategory.category}
                                                //viewModel.chipArray
                                                ForEach(catFilter) { data in
                                                    ChipItemView( isSelected: data.isSelected, systemImage: data.systemImage, imageType: data.imageType,
                                                             titleKey: data.titleKey)
                                                    .padding(.all, 3)
                                                    .padding(.horizontal, 3)
                                                    .alignmentGuide(.leading) { dimension in
                                                        if (abs(width - dimension.width) > geo.size.width) {
                                                            width = 0
                                                            height -= dimension.height
                                                        }
                                                        let result = width
                                                        if data.id == viewModel.chipArray.last!.id {
                                                            width = 0
                                                        } else {
                                                            width -= dimension.width
                                                        }
                                                        return result
                                                    } //:END OF LEADING ALIGNMENT
                                                    .alignmentGuide(.top) { dimension in
                                                        let result = height
                                                        if data.id == viewModel.chipArray.last!.id {
                                                            height = 0
                                                        }
                                                        return result
                                                    } //:END OF TOP ALIGNMENT
                                                } //:END OF CHIP FOR
                                            } //:END OF CATEGORY SECTION
                                        }//:END OF CATEGORY FOR
                                    } //:END OF LAZY VGRID
                                }) //:END OF ZSTACK
                                Spacer()
                                Text("Current Item Count \(customdrink.myDrinkGarnishCount)")
                                    .padding(.top, 25)
                                    .padding(.bottom, 25)
                            } //:END OF VSTACK
                            .padding(.horizontal, 5)
                            .padding(.bottom, 25)
                            .overlay(
                                GeometryReader { proxy -> Color in
                                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                        if startOffset == 0 {
                                            self.startOffset = proxy.frame(in: .global).minY
                                        } //: END OF IF
                                        
                                        let offset = proxy.frame(in: .global).minY
                                        self.scrollViewOffset = offset - startOffset
                                        
                                        //print(self.scrollViewOffset)
                                        
                                    } //: END OF DISPATCH QUEUE
                                    
                                    return Color.clear
                                    
                                } //: END OF GEOMETRY READER
                                    .frame(width: 0, height: 0 )
                                ,alignment: .top
                                
                            ) //: END OF OVERLAY
                        }//:END OF SCROLLVIEW
                        .overlay(
                            
                            Button(action: {
                                proxyReader.scrollTo("SCROLL_TO_TOP", anchor: .top)
                                
                            }, label: {
                                Text("BACK TO TOP")
                                    .font(.system(size: 15, weight: .semibold))
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                                    .padding()
                                    .background(Color(.blue))
                                    .clipShape(Capsule())
                                    .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.09), radius: 5, x: 5, y: 5)
                            })
                            .padding(.trailing)
                            .padding(.bottom, getSafeArea().bottom == 0 ? 12: 0)
                            .frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .bottomTrailing)
                            .opacity(-scrollViewOffset > 250 ? 1 : 0)
                            .animation(.easeOut,value: pulsateButton)
                            
                            
                            ,alignment: .bottomTrailing
                        ) //:END OF OVERLAY
                        .onAppear() {
                            pulsateButton.toggle()
                        } //: END OF OVERLAY ON APPEAR
                    } //: END OF SCROLL READER
                } //:END OF ZSTACK
            } //:END OF GEOMETRY READER
        } //:END OF OUT VSTACK
    } //:END OF BODY/VIEW
} //:END OF STRUCT
                                   
                                   extension View {

                                       func getSafeArea() -> UIEdgeInsets {

                                           let keySafeArea = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes

                                                       .filter({$0.activationState == .foregroundActive})

                                                       .map({$0 as? UIWindowScene})

                                                       .compactMap({$0})

                                                       .first?.windows

                                                       .filter({$0.isKeyWindow}).first

                                   //        print(keyWindow?.safeAreaInsets ?? "Nothing")


                                   //        return UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.safeAreaInsets ?? UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)

                                           return (keySafeArea?.safeAreaInsets ?? UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0))


                                       } //: END OF FUNCTION
                                   } //: END OF VIEW EXTENSION

//MARK: - PREVIEW

struct ChipContainerView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ChipContainerView()
            .environmentObject(customDrink())
    }
}
```

This all works correctly and the selections or unselections works correctly and deletes or adds to the array it's populating. Gets the correct counts and tracks accordingly.

Where I am running into the issue is when I bring this up in the app view the selection stops working.  I am able to select the 5 items that I allow up to, however I can't unselect so there for the downstream array is not being updated.

I am not sure how to pass this information to or from the parent level so the isSelected works through out.

I did try to create a selection option in the custom drink class called myDrinkGarnishSelected however, when this is implemented it highlights all of the chips or unselects all of the chips so you only get to select 1 chip instead of up to 5.

Here is the app\parent view

```
import SwiftUI

struct Garnish1TypeView: View {
    
    //MARK: - PROPERTIES
    
    @EnvironmentObject var customdrink: customDrink
    @StateObject var viewModel = ChipsViewModel()

    
    //MARK: - BODY
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            Color(.gray)
                .ignoresSafeArea()

            VStack(spacing: 10) {
                Text("Select Your Garnish")
                    .font(.title)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                ChipContainerView(viewModel: viewModel)
                Spacer()

            }//:END OF VSTACK
            .padding(.horizontal, 10)

        } //:END OF ZSTACK
        
    } //: END OF VIEW/BODY
    
} //:END OF STRUCT

//MARK: - PREVIEW

struct Garnish1TypeView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Garnish1TypeView()
            .environmentObject(customDrink())
    }
}
```

Here is the updated content view as well.  So everything should be able to go into a blank project.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var customdrink = customDrink()
//    @EnvironmentObject var customdrink: customDrink
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Garnish1TypeView()
                .environmentObject(customdrink)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Any support is appreciated.  I at a bit of a loss here on what to do and or what I am missing.

Comment: “State” Should only be used inside SwiftUI views

Comment: There are all swiftui views

Comment: `ChipModel` is not a `View` and has `@State` in it. You should consider using `@StateObject var viewModel = ChipsViewModel()` and have **only one** such `viewModel` that you pass around.

Comment: ChipModel isn’t as said above but there are several other little issues like using “ObservedObject” for initializing it should be “StateObject”. Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.
You should reduce your code to the least amount required to reproduce your issue if you need further help.

Comment: Note, currently you have two separate `viewModel`.
In `Garnish1TypeView`, you should have **one**  `@StateObject var viewModel = ChipsViewModel()`.
And in `ChipContainerView` you should have `@ObservedObject var viewModel: ChipsViewModel`.

Comment: I did update the code above.  However based on the suggestions. The code is now working.  I didn't realize that I was nesting view after view.  Appreciate the assistance. Of course this works when complied however when looking at it through preview it doesn't appear to work correctly.  Is there a way to get this working in preview as well or just take it as a win and compile the app each time?